# Why do I still have png's after implementing vector drawable support library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

Pretty much what the title says. I have 2 png's outside of pure xml files for vector drawables and I'm using the vector drawable support library.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

I decompiled the apk that builds from this with apktool and found that there are still about 150 png's in my res folder, even though I only have 2 in my res. Did I do something wrong in the implementation?

Comment: This looks OK if your gradle plugin is version 2+, is it? One thing to try would be to clean your project (Build > Clean Project), in case pngs were generated before you had the correct setup in place and your build just needs a fresh start

Comment: When I removed all `android:fillType="..."` attributes from my vector drawables (in `<path>` elements), the problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

Because `VectorDrawableCompat` generates PNGs at compile time.

It's neccesary, because older APIs (<19) do not support vector drawables. Make sure that your Gradle Plugin is 1.5.0 or newer.

For not getting the PNGs, you must set **minSDK** to **21**, and **not** use VectorDrawableCompat.

See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)

Comment: Ok, so I'll still have to go through apk splitting. Do you know of any good examples or tutorials of/for api apk splitting? I could only find the official tutorial, which wasn't that much help.

Comment: **You’ll be able to use VectorDrawableCompat back to API 7 and AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat on all API 11 and higher devices.** http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: Hey, so I did set my minSDK to 21 and then removed the appCompat library and vectorDrawables line, but I'm still generating png's. What else could be causing this?

Comment: This shouldn't be an accepted answer, it's incorrect information.

Comment: Reding [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html), PNG generation paragraph states what I say.

Comment: @LewisMcGeary, what is the correct information on this. I also understood webo80's response to be right.

Comment: @TashPemhiwa if you use VectorDrawables in your project, but **don't** enable the VectorDrawable support library, then Android Studio will generate pngs if your minSDK is lower than 21. If you use VectorDrawables and **enable** the support library, like the person who asked this question(`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`) then pngs **will not** be generated, because it will use VectorDrawableCompat for devices below API 21.

Comment: Thanks @LewisMcGeary, that clarifies things for me.